# iOS - BLE disconnects and does not reconnect

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device that I connect with my application. I have managed to auto-connect to it the first time the application is used and I have also managed to make the application work if the device gets turned off and then on again. BUT the last one works only if the device gets turned off for like less than 20-30 minutes.

If I turn on the device in less than 30 minutes the application will reconnect to it automatically and read its data. But after 30 minutes although when I turn on the device it appears to reconnect to the iPhone, the application does seem to reconnect to it and read data.

Any suggestions, hints or tips? Thank you all in advance.

---

EDIT: adding some code as requested

```
/*
 Invoked whenever an existing connection with the peripheral is torn down.
 Reset local variables
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    self.connected = NO;

    if( self.peripheral )
    {
        [self.peripheral setDelegate:nil];
        self.peripheral = nil;
    }
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[myService] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
}
```

Comment: Are you keeping a strong reference to the `CBPeripheral` of interest?

Comment: @Abhinav I was, but this was blocking the reconnection after a few minutes. It was trying to reconnect to the referenced device and nothing happened. Now I clean-up that reference on disconnection and start scanning again.

Comment: I was wondering if you are following the reconnection flow chart as mentioned in [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html)

Comment: @Abhinav Until yesterday I did follow the reconnection flow chart but it would reconnect well for the first 10 minutes. After 10 minutes of being shut down it wouldn't reconnect again at all. I had to disconnect the device and pair again.

Comment: Please show your code for `didDisconnect`

Comment: @Paulw11 Please check again. I added the method.

Comment: All you should do in that method is set self.connected to no and then call connectPeripheral again straight away with the existing peripheral object. No need to scan

Comment: @Paulw11 Will this work if the device is turned of for more than 1 hour for example?

Comment: This will work if days elapse before the peripheral is seen again although you will probably need to implement core Bluetooth state restoration